# ...the man "in which" OR "in who" the implant was integrated?

Tags: adverbs, pronouns

Since, nowadays, "which" and "who" are more interchangeably used than formal Oxford English would suggest, (such as using "It was the company who...") which of the below option sounds more correct?

A) Jeff was the man, in WHO the implant was integrated.
B) Jeff was the man, in WHICH the implant was integrated.

Thank you!
J

Comment: I'm tempted to say that the correct form is actually 'whom,' but don't quote me on that.

Comment: I tend to agree, but it sounds exceptionally formal.

Comment: In terms of sheer readability, I'd recommend rewriting the sentence entirely to remove the subordinate clause. Like, for example, `The implant was integrated in Jeff`. Of course, this is probably just my general hatred for subordinate clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(A) is better, but you should removed the comma: "Jeff was the man in whom the implant was integrated". With the comma,"in whom the implant was integrated" becomes a nonrestrictive clause modifying "Jeff", rather than a restrictive clause modifying "the man".